# Resource from Resource dictionary not getting applied

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a resource dictionary called mainpageresources.xaml stored in folder Resources as follows:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CommandsTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2,6">
                        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=Command}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

In my MainWindow.xaml file I am trying to use this resource for an Item Control as follows but it doesn't seem to work. If I remove the comments from the below ItemsControl that works fine.

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Demo" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/MainWindowResources.xaml">
                </ResourceDictionary>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ResourceKey=CommandsTemplate}">            
        </ItemsControl>

        <!--<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Margin="2,6">
                        <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=Command}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
                        </Hyperlink>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>-->
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Is there anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ItemTemplate` is there for you to indicate what the template for each *item* should be. Instead, use a `ContentPresenter`.

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" 
                  ContentTemplate="{StaticResource CommandsTemplate}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

That does not look right at all, i.e. the resource expanded:

```
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Commands}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2,6">
                            <Hyperlink Command="{Binding Path=Command}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" />
                            </Hyperlink>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Probably not what you want, no `ItemsSource` set, hence no items generated, and the `ItemTemplate` is what presumably should be your whole control. To just reference something use a `ContentPresenter`.